# How to float an element to right

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

In the below HTML code the `btnContinue` appears beneanth `txtClientID`  how can i make `btnContinue` appear next to `txtClientID`.  `style="float: right;` didn't help.

Snippet :

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Client ID</label>
            <input type="text" id="txtClientID" name="clientID" class="form-control input-md" />

            <button type="button" id="btnContinue" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="SetEverifyAccount()">
              <i ng-if="IsSaving" class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i> Continue
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Float txtClientID to the left, and btnContinue to the right. Floating only the second one to the right won't work. you need to do both. Or you can use Bootstrap's helper classes: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-floats

Comment: try wrapping that button with a class `text-right`

Comment: form class="form-inline" ?

Answer (score 1):

The best option is to use another div and [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and make it `display: flex; flex-basis: row;` and maybe `justify-content: space-between` but not necessarily.

Answer (score 1):

How about wrapping all of them inside an `input-group`?
Checkout my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b0dx4kd8/). It could be helpful.

Snippet from fiddle :

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" id="txtClientID" name="clientID" class="form-control input-md" placeholder="Client ID"/>
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" id="btnContinue" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="SetEverifyAccount()">
              <i ng-if="IsSaving" class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i> Continue
            </button>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this :

```css
.control-label {
  padding-top: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-xs-2">Client ID</label>
    <div class="col-xs-7">
      <input type="text" id="txtClientID" name="clientID" class=" form-control input-md" />
    </div>

    <button type="button" id="btnContinue" class="btn btn-success col-xs-3" ng-click="SetEverifyAccount()">
      <i ng-if="IsSaving" class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i> Continue
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also check : [Align to right with offset](http://www.bootply.com/91916)

Comment: @claudios Thank you. Just checked your solution that's good too.